# Detect nearby wifi without connecting to it

Tags: android, wifi

I want my app to "do something" when a wifi is nearby. But the phone doesn't connect to it. I don't have the password. For example, if the wifi University0001 is reachable I would like to silent my phone but I don't have the password to University0001.

Is there a way to have a broadcast receiver that triggers when new (not connected) ssid are around?
I would not like to have a "timer" to periodically check new SSIDs. I am asking for a receiver to trigger when new networks are around and maybe then check for the one I want.

I hope to be clear.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer but, to do what you want to achieve, there is an app called "Tasker". Do check it out.

Comment: Well, the idea is to build my own app.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But tasker does the job and much more other automation stuff. Sorry but I dont know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a broadcast receiver that triggers when new (not connected) ssid are around?

yes there is.

if your WIFI is on, **and you are not currently connected to a WIFI network** - the system periodically scan for available access points. when it will detect new visible access point it will send the [SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) broadcast.

you can register to that broadcast, and when it receives - get from `WifiManager` the scan results:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    WifiManager wifiManager (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);    
    List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
}
```

if you are already connected to a WIFI network - then you won't have any choice but to trigger the scan yourself periodically...

**be careful:**

performing from this receiver long operations (such network requests..) any time it receives is a bad approach - you'll drain the users battery very fast.

Comment: Great!! You are right about the battery drain. Am I asking for too much if there is a way to get triggered only when there is a change in the results?

Comment: I believe there is no way to get broadcast only for changes.